# Reloading fragment in view pager by radio button click

Tags: android, onclick, android-viewpager

I have view pager and fragments to show some question on it .I set option of questions as radio buttons. I need to set answer so that it will be only shown when i click one of the option .I have on click function in view pager and answer on fragment class .But how i reload the current fragment view on clicking radiobutton.(when i try to reload the view automaticaly goes back to first view ).?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve problem by setting text view on view pager activity and setting on click on same class.I receive page number by function viewPager.getcurrentItem();(viewpager is object of class ViewPager).

Answer (score 1):

Follow this steps:

You have to extend from FragmentStatePagerAdapter instead FragmentPagerAdapter 'cause the last one never change contained fragments. Then in extended adapter add one more method:

```
@Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    return POSITION_NONE;
}
```

In you main activity class, that contain `ViewPager` create method:

```
public YourExtendedApdaterClass getAdapter(){
    return instanceOfAdapter;
}
```

After that in you fragment call this wherever you want to update fragments:

```
((YourActivityClass)getActivity()).getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Sorry i don't understand what you mention.Any way i solve problem by setting text view on view pager activity and setting on click on same class.I receive page number by function viewPager.getcurrentItem();(viewpager is object of class ViewPager). I avoid reloading so that it still make things bad.